# Having a problem with batch files not running multiple lines of commands

Tags: batch-file

Currently, I am trying to make a batch file that disables some settings for my teredo client, which ultimately fixes an error with my Xbox app.  When I run my current batch file, it only inputs the first command and does not progress any further.  I'm not very familiar with batch files and I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

I have tried making multiple batch files for each line and then calling them all within a general file, but everything seems to just run the first command.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off
netsh & 
int teredo &
set state disabled &
int ipv6 &
set teredo client
```

Essentially, I expect the command prompt to pop up and give me multiple responses to each individual line, such as "netsh interface teredo>" after the line int teredo is run, but the only response that I receive is "netsh>".

Comment: Lose all the ampersands.

Comment: @Noodles. Won't work, nesh creates its own shell.

Comment: `@echo off` and `netsh` are batch commands, but the rest are `netsh`.-specific commands that must be placed in a separate script and then called by `netsh exec "your_netsh_script_file.txt"`...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a batch file, called something like **mynetsh.cmd** and add this:

```
(echo int teredo
echo set state disabled
echo int ipv6
echo set teredo client
)>answer.txt
netsh exec answer.txt
```

It will echo each command to a file, netsh will then read the commands from the file. No need to delete the answer file as it will be overwritten next time you run the script.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help., Please consider marking the answer as correct, by selecting the grey tick mark next to it, but only if you feel it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`@echo off 
(
netsh
int teredo
set state disabled
int ipv6
set teredo client
)`

It worked the first time but not the second.

Put this command in your batch file:

`netsh -f test.txt`

test.txt:

```
int teredo 
set state disabled 
int ipv6 
set teredo client
```

[NETSH](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/netsh.php)

[Use NETSH scripts to manage a Windows information network](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-your-skills-netsh-scripts-add-network-functionality-to-batch-files/)

> The right way to get the job done actually involves creating two
>   different scripts. The first script would be the script containing all
>   of the NETSH commands. In this case, the script would contain the
>   commands DHCP and SHOW SERVER. The other script would be a batch file
>   that calls NETSH in command mode. However, the way that the NETSH
>   command is entered forces NETSH to switch from command mode to batch
>   mode.
>
> In this particular case, the batch file would call the NETSH shell but
>   use the EXEC command and the name of the batch-mode script as
>   parameters. For example, if you saved the batch-mode script as
>   TEST.TXT, then the line in the batch file that runs the script would
>   be NETSH EXEC TEST.TXT. When you execute the batch file, the command
>   interpreter would read the line, load the NETSH shell, switch to batch
>   mode, load the script TEST.TXT, execute the script, and then return to
>   the command prompt (or to the next line in the batch file) when the
>   script completed.